# how to embed image into flex grid column

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder, flex-mx

Is there an easy way to embed an image into a flex grid column? Something similar to:

```
<mx:DataGridColumn width="23" src="images/testimage.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an item renderer like this one:

```
<mx:DataGridColumn>
<mx:itemRenderer>
    <mx:Component>
        <mx:Image source="images/testimage.jpg"/>
    </mx:Component>
</mx:itemRenderer>
```